# Using LDAP/AD to control access to a program - what is the account password?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, passwords, ldap

Despite the fact that I know almost nothing about LDAP and AD apart from the basics of what it does (in this case, Microsoft) I have been asked to modify a program so that it will retrieve the user's email address.  The application can be configured to use LDAP.  I'm not sure exactly how it is using it - something to do with synchronising the application's passwords with the user's LDAP password.  The application has a password, which might not be the same as the user's LDAP password.  There is some mechanism to synchronise the passwords - but in theory that shouldn't concern me - I'm told that it works.

Of course, we didn't have an LDAP server here for me to try things out on.

So I have installed Windows 2003 server on a PC, and enabled LDAP on it (a massive learning curve, I can tell you).  I have added a couple of users. and even managed to get one of them to be a member of Domain Admin.

In the application I'm working on, there is a setup facility to configure the connection to the LDAP.  This has a helpful Test Settings button.  If I put in the server IP address and the port number, and press Test Settings then it tells me that the test was successful.  Hmm - that seems unlikely.  There are other pieces of information it asks for:

- Service Account DN
- Service Account Password
- User Account Container.

If I leave those blank, and save the settings then I am now able to start up the application and put only the username in with any or no password - which is not right, of course - it should prevent me from starting up my app.  So I can only assume that I need to set up those three pieces of info.

The LDAP server I created is called, I believe, `Aware.Server`

So I have put `DC=AWare, DC=Server` into the Service account DN (I'm just guessing here, not really sure what should be in there) and `cn=Users, DC=AWare.Server` into the User Account Container (again, I don't really know what that is, or what is meant to be in there).

I have no idea what the Service Account Password is, so I leave that blank.

When I press Test Settings it asks me for a user name and password.

If I leave those blank then it says that the test was successful.  I'm beginning to worry.

If I put in a user name that I have entered into LDAP, with a password, it says that the test was successful.

Actually, if I put anything at all into those boxes, it says that it is successful.

However, if I put something into the Service Account Password then the test is not successful - it says that the service account supplied has either an invalid user name or password.

So the main question at this point is - how do I find out what the service account password is?

And is the behaviour that I'm getting to be expected?
Thanks
Steve

Code for validating sign on includes:

```
Public Shared Function ValidateUser(ByVal server As String, ByVal port As Integer, ByVal userBase As String, ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal bindUser As String, ByVal bindPassword As String) As LdapValidatorResult
            Dim retVal As New LdapValidatorResult
            Dim conn As New Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection()
            Try

                'connect to the specificed server for user validation
                conn.Connect(server, port)

                retVal.Result = LdapValidatorResultType.Success
                Try
                    'now authenticate to we can then go on to see if the username specificed exists
                    conn.Bind(bindUser, bindPassword)

                    'construct the distinguished name to uniquely id the specified user
                    Dim searchString As String = String.Format("CN={0},{1}", userName, userBase)

                    'look to see if the user attempting to login to a-ware exists
                    Dim sResults As LdapSearchResults = conn.Search(searchString, Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection.SCOPE_SUB, Nothing, Nothing, False) '"(&(!(objectClass=computer)))"
                    If sResults.hasMore Then

                        Try

                            'now validate the user with the password as the final check
                            Dim userDN As String = sResults.next.DN
                            conn.Bind(userDN, password)
                            retVal.Result = LdapValidatorResultType.Success

                        Catch ex As Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapException
                            If ex.ResultCode = Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapException.INVALID_CREDENTIALS Then
                                retVal.Result = LdapValidatorResultType.InvalidUserNameOrPassword
                            End If
                            retVal.ExceptInfo = ex
                        End Try

                    Else
                        retVal.Result = LdapValidatorResultType.NonExistentUser


                    End If
                Catch ex As Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapException
                    Select Case ex.ResultCode
                        Case Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapException.INVALID_CREDENTIALS
                            retVal.Result = LdapValidatorResultType.InvalidBindUserNameOrPassword
                        Case Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapException.CONNECT_ERROR
                            retVal.Result = LdapValidatorResultType.ServerDown
                    End Select

                    retVal.ExceptInfo = ex
                End Try

            Catch ex As Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapException
                Dim cause As System.Net.Sockets.SocketException = TryCast(ex.Cause, System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
                If cause IsNot Nothing Then
                    Select Case cause.ErrorCode
                        Case 1101
                            retVal.Result = LdapValidatorResultType.InvalidNameIp
                        Case 1106
                            retVal.Result = LdapValidatorResultType.RefusedConnectionOnPort
                        Case 10060
                            retVal.Result = LdapValidatorResultType.ServerDown
                    End Select
                End If
                retVal.ExceptInfo = ex
            End Try

            Return retVal
        End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it wants you to create a user account in your domain for the app to use.  Every object has a distinguished name (DN).  So it's asking for the DN of the user you created and its password, as well as the DN of the container that you created the user in.  I can't tell what your domain DNS name is, but I'm guessing it's AWare.Server.  So, if you create a user with username appuser in the default Users container with the password P@ssw0rd, then you would give the following:

Service Account DN: CN=appuser,CN=Users,DC=AWare,DC=Server
Service Account Password: P@ssw0rd
User Account Container: CN=Users,DC=AWare,DC=Server

Comment: Thanks for that - I will give that a go.  Any idea how I find out (or set) the server service account password, please? Or am I misunderstanding what you've said (very possible - this is a whole new world of pain for me :-) )
I think that you are right that the server DNS name is AWare.Server.

Comment: @SteveKnight You set the password yourself when you create the account.

Comment: Still having troubles with this I'm afraid (been working on other things meanwhile...).  Part of the problem is that I'm not sure what the Service Account is.  Presumably it's not the same thing as a user account.  Can I create more than one service account, and if so, how do I do that, please?